# Sendgrid on Compute Engine not working

Tags: postfix-mta, google-compute-engine, sendgrid

I setup Postfix with sendgrid just like the guide here: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail?hl=en#postfixsendgrid

but it's not working. when i run the test command:

```
printf 'Subject: test\r\n\r\npassed' | /usr/sbin/sendmail myemail@gmail.com
```

I get this error in the log:

```
Sep  1 11:58:12 instance-1 postfix/qmgr[23412]: 8205A1E38: from=<*******@instance-1.c.mindful-vial-682.internal>, size=301, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  1 11:58:12 instance-1 postfix/smtp[23422]: warning: SASL authentication failure: No worthy mechs found
Sep  1 11:58:12 instance-1 postfix/smtp[23422]: 8205A1E38: SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server smtp.sendgrid.net[208.43.76.147]: no mechanism available
Sep  1 11:58:13 instance-1 postfix/smtp[23422]: warning: SASL authentication failure: No worthy mechs found
Sep  1 11:58:13 instance-1 postfix/smtp[23422]: 8205A1E38: to=<myemail@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.sendgrid.net[208.43.76.146]:2525, delay=0.62, delays=0.01/0.02/0.59/0, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (SASL
 authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server smtp.sendgrid.net[208.43.76.146]: no mechanism available)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using debian, you'll need to install `libsasl2-modules` as well:

```
apt-get install libsasl2-modules
```

That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thank you! Spent 2 hours going through the web and config files without any success. This finally solved it!

Comment: This worked for me too (using Ubuntu 14/Postfix/Sendgrid).

Answer (score 2):

Or using a yum (i.e., RedHat, Fedora, CentOS):

```
yum install cyrus-sasl-plain
```

found this solution in [sendgrid docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/postfix.html)

Answer (score 0):

try reading the solution for "No worthy mechs found" error documented at [1].

Kind Regards
Paolo

[1] - http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_policy

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that was able to resolve this issue on Google Compute Engine was to statically link my sendgrid credentials in the postfix config file:

```
# Sendgrid Settings
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = static:SENDGRID_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_HERE:PASSWORD_HERE
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_security_level = may
header_size_limit = 4096000
relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:587
```

I found this solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9791763/2174832)